# How to select data between yesterday at specific time to today specific time in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have one Requirement where I have to show the records between specific date and time every day  eg. between yesterday 9 Am to Today 9 Am

```
Select * from sales where saledate between '24-OCT-17 09:00:00' to '25-OCT-17 09:00:00'
```

in oracle.

but not getting idea how to do this.

Comment: `between` means both yesterday at 9 AM precisely and today at 9 AM precisely will be included in the result, is that the desired behavior? If you do that, records with the time of exactly 9 AM will be counted twice.

Comment: ok we can modified like this '24-OCT-17 08:59:59' to '25-OCT-17 09:00:00'

Comment: err... No, you probably want the end to be 08:59:59, not the beginning. And it is better to avoid "between" and instead write `>= (start) and < (end)` That way you are making crystal clear that 9 AM on the previous day is included and 9 AM today is excluded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

9 AM *today* can be coded as

```
trunc(sysdate) + 9/24
```

and 9 AM *yesterday* as

```
trunc(sysdate) - 1 + 9/24
```

Alternatively,

```
trunc(sysdate) + interval '9' hour
```

and

```
trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' day + interval '9' hour
```

The calculations for "yesterday" can be simplified ( - 15/24 instead of - 1 + 9/24, and similarly for `interval` ) - but it is better to write the code the way I did, since it is clearer - easier to understand and maintain.

`trunc(sysdate)` means midnight (00:00:00) at the *beginning* of today. In date arithmetic, `1` means one day; `9/24` means 9 hours.

The WHERE clause may be written as

```
where saledate >= trunc(sysdate) - 1 + 9/24 and saledate < trunc(sysdate) + 9/24
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert you strings to date :

```
Select * from sales 
where saledate between to_date('24-OCT-17 09:00:00','dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('25-OCT-17 09:00:00','dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss');
```